# How to include arguments for MSI installation using WMI

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wmi

I'm using wmi along with the 'call install true...' format to install an msi remotely:

```
wmic /node:"[host]" /user:"[user]" /password:"[password]" ENVIRONMENT="RELEASE" product call install true, "", "\\[host]\D$\WebsitesDirectory\[name].msi"
```

This works fine except that I can't get the format right to include the command line arguments I would normally use with msiexec. I have declared a variable called "ENVIRONMENT" in Wix. In this case, it should be ENVIRONMENT="RELEASE". Can anyone show me the correct format or point me towards the documentation that shows it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the answer. It appears the arguments go into the first pair of quotes after 'true':

```
... product call install true, "ENVIRONMENT=RELEASE", ...
```

Comment: Do you know how to pass other arguments, e.g. directory where it should be installed? Say I install all my services in C:\Services folder, how do I pass that to the second "Options" parameter?